# neo4j - How I can change the max package size? (Adjusted frame length exceeds)

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, py2neo

When I am importing data in neo4j with py2neo I receive this error. Always in the same row.

I think is related to the size of the package but I didn't find any post related to this.

```
 Adjusted frame length exceeds 65535: 65537 - discarded
```

btw, I don't know anything related to Java.

Extended log:

```
2018-06-07 22:59:33.536+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.p.HouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection: [id: 0x13bb4727, L:/127.0.0.1:7687 - R:/127.0.0.1:48830] Adjusted frame length exceeds 65535: 65537 - discarded
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 65535: 65537 - discarded
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.fail(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:522)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.failIfNecessary(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:500)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.exceededFrameLength(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:387)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:430)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:343)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:808)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:304)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the error. This is a known issue in Neo4j and will be resolved in the 3.4.1 patch. For more details, the relevant pull request is here:
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/11918

Comment: Thanks, Nigel, and when this release will be published?

Comment: We're aiming for next week.